# Predicting logistic regression in R with missing values

Tags: r, regression, logistic

Can logistic regression provide a predicted value for observations with missing values?

Here are the details:

- I have a file with about 10K rows, about 3K have all complete values for all variables.
- I ran a logistic regression (`glm`) to estimate coefficients and significance for each predictor
- Now when I try to predict the probabilities of the dependent variable using the fitted model, I only get values for the 3K rows that all have values for the independent variables

I would like to have some predicted probability for all 10K rows, is that even possible? How do I do that in R? I have tried `na.action=na.exclude/na.pass` and that only provides values for the 3K rows.

Comment: If some rows are missing data a common approach is to use [data imputation techniques](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99334/fast-missing-data-imputation-in-r-for-big-data-that-is-more-sophisticated-than-s)

Comment: Short answer: NO.