# Missing data imputation that can handle large data

Tags: r, machine-learning, missing-data, large-data, data-imputation

I am looking for a reasonably scaling missing data imputation approach for big data (e.g. a well-scaling version of kNN - the standard versions we tried so far just ran out of memory) that fulfills the following criteria:

- takes what we know about records into account (i.e. not just a naive median/majority class approach, e.g. if we impute exact age and we have a categorical variable like "school child", "working age" and "retired", then I'd want an imputation that tends to impute young ages for "school child" records with missing age)
- scales to a dataset with 300 to 1000 predictors and about 5 million records
- reasonable memory requirement (for example on the system I use, I can get $\leq 256$ GB)
- bearable runtime (let's say < 1 hour on a reasonably decent recent Xeon CPU, or if parallelization up to 20 of them with Infiniband)
- ideally automatically deals with a mixture of continuous, binary and categorical predictors
- ideally implemented in R (or python)

I noticed [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99334/fast-missing-data-imputation-in-r-for-big-data-that-is-more-sophisticated-than-s), but the data in question there is much smaller and a lot of time has passed (giving me some hope that new options have become available).

Comment: If you have 5 million records and 1000 predictors, you're at 40GB for data storage if everything is double precision; you'll likely not be able to come anywhere close to your memory requirement.  Also, in high dimensions, kNN (with Euclidean distance) isn't so useful, as everything becomes almost equally far apart from everything else.

Comment: @jbowman, thanks. I  will check what I can maximally get. The data did fit into memory, so I guess it is more (I was hunting for system documentation, but could not find it).

Comment: @jbowman On the particular system I can use, I can have up to 256 GB. I'll update the question.

Comment: Are you trying to do single imputation or multiple imputation with pooling?

Comment: No strong opinion either way.

Comment: What is this question ("I am looking for a...") about? Is it about kNN? You sum up a lot of numbers but why (the actual problem is not stated with similar detail)?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : The aim is to do prediction modeling with the (imputed) data as predictors. The hope is that doing some not too simplistic imputation will lead to better predictions that some naïve median/majority class imputation.

Comment: When the aim is some *'not too simplistic imputation'* then it might be useful to explain more about the *specific problem* rather than the bunch of hardware available. The way that you are gonna do imputation is, in the first placae, I guess, more dependent on the specifics of the abstract problem rather than the size of your computer. The question is very broad at this moment.

Comment: We are assuming MCAR right? Also have you tried something like [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5394) where they essentially use an autoencoder to impute missing data?

Comment: @usεr11852 MAR i.e. the other variables really hold information that should be accounted for. I had not looked at that, yet.

Comment: If the goal is to make predictions have you considered using a model that can deal with missing values, like say Gradient Boosted Trees? (I'm thinking of XGBoost specifically).

Comment: Yes, we've tried that. There's some other interesting models we'd like to try that don't, that's why it would be great to have options for explicit imputation.