# Imputation for Big Data

Tags: regularization, data-imputation, large-data

I have a dataset with 78 observations and 25000 variables.I am trying to apply logistic regression with shrinkage methods(penalties like SCAD,MCP,LASSO).The problem is that the commands ncvreg(ncvreg library) and cv.ncpen(ncpen library),do not run,because I have lots of NA's in the data.I am trying to do imputation,but I cannot find a library that works for such a number of variables.Any help?

Comment: Do the NAs affect some of the variables but not others? Or are some of the observations missing data for most of the variables?

Comment: the NA;s affect all  the variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast missing data imputation in R for big data that is more sophisticated than simply imputing the means?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99334/fast-missing-data-imputation-in-r-for-big-data-that-is-more-sophisticated-than-s) The structure of the data set in that question seems quite similar to yours. If you tried `mice` or other libraries and they didn't work, please edit the question to specify how they failed.